# How do I remove the Hour field from the flutter_datetime_picker package?

Tags: flutter

I am designing a Stopwatch kind of Application.I have been able to display the time in HH:MM:SS format.But I want it in MM:SS format.COuld anyone help me to do this.I tried set showSecondsColumn:False, but The second's field is going off.I have put the code below

```
RaisedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                DatePicker.showTimePicker(context,
                    showTitleActions: true,
                    showSecondsColumn: true, onConfirm: (time) {
                  setState(() {
                    _selectedTime = DateFormat("HH-mm-ss").format(time);
                  });
                }, locale: LocaleType.en);
              },
              child: Text("Show Time picker"),
            ),
          ],
```

Answer (score 2):

You can copy paste run full code below 
You can extend `CommonPickerModel` 
Step 1: In `layoutProportions` hide Hour with `[0, 1, 1],` 0 means not show
Step 2: Change `leftDivider` and `rightDivider` to space or : 
Step 3: Use  `DatePicker.showPicker` and pass `pickerModel: CustomPicker(currentTime: DateTime.now())`

code snippet

```
class CustomPicker extends CommonPickerModel {
...
 @override
  List<int> layoutProportions() {
    return [0, 1, 1];
  }

 @override
  String leftDivider() {
    return "";
  }

  @override
  String rightDivider() {
    return ":";
  }

DatePicker.showPicker(context, showTitleActions: true,
                    onChanged:  ...
                    , onConfirm: ...
                    , pickerModel: CustomPicker(currentTime: DateTime.now()),
                    locale: LocaleType.en);
```

working demo

[image]

full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_datetime_picker/flutter_datetime_picker.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';

void main() => runApp(new MyApp());

class CustomPicker extends CommonPickerModel {
  String digits(int value, int length) {
    return '$value'.padLeft(length, "0");
  }

  CustomPicker({DateTime currentTime, LocaleType locale})
      : super(locale: locale) {
    this.currentTime = currentTime ?? DateTime.now();
    this.setLeftIndex(this.currentTime.hour);
    this.setMiddleIndex(this.currentTime.minute);
    this.setRightIndex(this.currentTime.second);
  }

  @override
  String leftStringAtIndex(int index) {
    if (index >= 0 && index < 24) {
      return this.digits(index, 2);
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  }

  @override
  String middleStringAtIndex(int index) {
    if (index >= 0 && index < 60) {
      return this.digits(index, 2);
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  }

  @override
  String rightStringAtIndex(int index) {
    if (index >= 0 && index < 60) {
      return this.digits(index, 2);
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  }

  @override
  String leftDivider() {
    return "";
  }

  @override
  String rightDivider() {
    return ":";
  }

  @override
  List<int> layoutProportions() {
    return [0, 1, 1];
  }

  @override
  DateTime finalTime() {
    return currentTime.isUtc
        ? DateTime.utc(
            currentTime.year,
            currentTime.month,
            currentTime.day,
            this.currentLeftIndex(),
            this.currentMiddleIndex(),
            this.currentRightIndex())
        : DateTime(
            currentTime.year,
            currentTime.month,
            currentTime.day,
            this.currentLeftIndex(),
            this.currentMiddleIndex(),
            this.currentRightIndex());
  }
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: new ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: new HomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  String _selectedTime;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Datetime Picker'),
      ),
      body: Center(
          child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          FlatButton(
              onPressed: () {
                DatePicker.showPicker(context, showTitleActions: true,
                    onChanged: (date) {
                  print('change $date in time zone ' +
                      date.timeZoneOffset.inHours.toString());
                }, onConfirm: (time) {
                  print('confirm $time');
                  _selectedTime = DateFormat("HH-mm-ss").format(time);
                  print(_selectedTime);
                },
                    pickerModel: CustomPicker(currentTime: DateTime.now()),
                    locale: LocaleType.en);
              },
              child: Text(
                'show custom time picker,\nyou can custom picker model like this',
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.blue),
              )),
          RaisedButton(
            onPressed: () {
              DatePicker.showTimePicker(context,
                  showTitleActions: true,
                  showSecondsColumn: true, onConfirm: (time) {
                setState(() {
                  _selectedTime = DateFormat("HH-mm-ss").format(time);
                  print(_selectedTime);
                });
              }, locale: LocaleType.en);
            },
            child: Text("Show Time picker"),
          ),
        ],
      )),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a Lot @chunhunghan .It is working.I am pretty new to flutter and u really helped me from stopping to break my head

Comment: Glad to help. please mark this as answer if it helps you. thanks